# A button does not move

Tags: java, swing

When I run this code, the controls button appears on the top. I want to change size of the button and the place of the button. I tried to use `setBounds()` method but it doesn't change anything.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class GameFrame
{

    public JFrame gameframe;
    public JPanel panel;
    public JButton b1;
    public JLabel lab;

    public GameFrame()
    {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui()
    {
        gameframe = new JFrame("Poop MAN");
        gameframe.setVisible(true);
        gameframe.setSize(800, 900);
        gameframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        b1 = new JButton("CONTROLS");
        b1.setBounds( 300,70,590,300);
        //b1.setSize(new Rectan

        panel.add(b1);


        gameframe.add(panel);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                new GameFrame();
        }
}
```

Comment: Google the terms "Java Layout Manager", it will give you enough information about how to place your widgets as you wish. Else you might get into this sort of problem again and again. And I would advise you never to use `setBounds` unless you _really_ know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you change the position or text of the button you need to call repaint() on the JFrame. Make sure the button is added to the JFrame first.

Comment: after this line of code gameframe.add(panel); call gameframe.repaint();

Comment: it doesnt do any changes

Comment: Is the panel the same size of the window? Have you tried setting the bounds of the panel? panel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);